# Multidimensional arrays in C with while loops

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array

I have created a program where the user enters the number of rows and columns of a multidimensional array and then prints the contents of it. But it only prints one row and not the whole array, why?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define rows 100
#define columns 100

int m_array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

int main(){
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int rows;
int columns;
do {
    printf("How many rows will be in the array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
} while (rows > ROWS || rows < 1);

do {
    printf("How many columns will be in the array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
} while (columns > COLUMNS || columns < 1);

printf("Data entry\n");
while (i < rows) {
    j=0;
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("Insert the element of the column %d and row %d\n", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &m_array[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
i = 0;
j = 0;
printf("These are the data\n");
while (i < rows) {
    printf("\n");
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("\t%d ", m_array[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

I know that it would be more handy with for loops but i want to do this code exclusively with while loops.

Here it is an example of input ad output:

Input

`2 rows 2 columns 1 value 2 value 3 value 4 value`

Output

`1 2`

`3 4`

Comment: When do you reset `j` in your print loop?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  You have to reset `j` to zero before you enter the second loop again.  This is one reason `for` loops are preferred; you get the reset for free.